# Programmatically adding tag to an SPWeb (Tags & Notes)

Tags: 2013, taxonomy, tagging

I've been tasked with adding metadata to a site's Tags.  I thought the SPWeb's Tags (Tags & Notes) would be found in the SPWeb.Fields collection, but have not found any field that contains tags that a manually put in the site.

Comment: Do you have the Taxonomy session (& term sets) in play already?

Comment: @Supiryo - Yes.  I misunderstood how the tags were being stored.  I assumed I could just pull them from the SPWeb.Fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create & retrieve Social Tags to/from a site URL & user profile by using the [SocialTagManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.socialdata.socialtagmanager%28v=office.15%29.aspx) & [SocialTag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.socialdata.socialtag%28v=office.15%29.aspx) Class.

An example of its usage is given in this Microsoft post -
[How to: Create and Retrieve a Social Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407956%28v=office.14%29.aspx)